# Wordpress theming

Tags: theme-development, themes

I created a wordpress theme i used free page builder called unyson used many plugins i built it successfully but when i copied whole theme and created zip file out of it and then uploaded it to newly installed wordpress i couldnt find my plugins although theme installed successfully but there was no plugins and any widgets that i created. can anyone answer why?? I am still learning wordpress templating m so confused and frustrated right now.

Comment: Plugins get installed in wp-content/plugins and usually also save settings and customsation information into the database. If you only copied the theme folder and didn't also copy that stuff then it's not going to come across.

Comment: Yeah i only copied theme folder not plugins folder files. How can i compress or copy files so that when i install theme into newly added wordpress it should ask or install plugins and widgets as well?. just the way a premium wordpress theme works.